# Can I put a boxplot on top of a .jpg image

Tags: r

I have a picture of an oyster which I want the boxplots to sit on top of. Is this possible? and if so, can anyone point me in the right direction to getting started.

I have no issue creating the boxplots, It's just I want them on the image.

I guess I'm creating a function

```
plotGraph<-function(boxplotArray[]) {
#import image

#loop through boxplots and put them on top of image

#render
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to take a look at `rasterImage()` from the `raster` package

Comment: You can add plots to the same plot window with `add = TRUE`.  I'd bet that with `rasterImage()` and a new plot that includes the `add = TRUE` argument, you could pretty easily make it happen.